# Making mocha "use strict" when running in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Is there a way to make Mocha run tests in strict mode when running on node?

Normally you can enable this in node by running `node --use_strict`. Is there a way to do the same thing for `mocha`?

Comment: The accepted answer is clearly wrong (it doesn't do the same thing as `node --use_strict`. Please consider accepting the other (upvoted) one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `--use_strict` to the mocha command.

So your command might look like this :

```
mocha ./test --recursive --use_strict
```

Comment: I was running into this, too. I ended up passing the `--use_strict` flag to my npm script for tests and got it to work.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the `--recursive` option is not related to this issue?

Comment: Yes, it's an example a command. You can remove if you think it's irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass --use_strict into mocha and this was done in purpose. Read [the discussion](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/1105) for details.

If you really want this behaviour you could fork mocha's sources or load [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-strict) npm module as a first thing in your tests.

Comment: this post seems outdated: a flag was added: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/1999

Comment: but it is relevant if somebody find them-selfs with old mocha for whatever reason, accepted answer do not state it's version based

Answer (score -7):

I would just start test scripts with 
`'use strict';`

Comment: It will only switch to strict mode for the test script itself, while what the `--use_strict` option for `node` does is switching to strict mode **recursively for all scripts** being required.